# read json file from androidTest

Tags: android, android-resources, android-testing

hello i'm trying to read json file located at resources folder in androidTest. I'm able to access json file located at resources folder in Test/resources but not in androidTest/resources.

I use following to get the json file in the Test/resources folder.

```
private fun getJson(path: String): String {
    val uri = this.javaClass.classLoader?.getResource(path)
    val file = File(uri?.path ?: "")
    return String(file.readBytes())
}
```

Is there a way i can access the file under androidTest/resources ?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 private fun getJson(fileName: Int): String {
        val inputStream = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext.resources.openRawResource(fileName)
        val s = Scanner(inputStream).useDelimiter("\\A")
        return if (s.hasNext()) s.next() else ""
    }
```